# NgbTypeahead leave incomplete text

Tags: html, typescript, bootstrap-5, ngb-typeahead

So I have the following input

```
<input
                id="agency"
                type="text"
                name="agency"
                class="form-control"
                formControlName="agency"
                [ngClass]="{ 'read-only': viewPage }"
                [ngbTypeahead]="searchAgency"
                [resultFormatter]="resultFormatAgencyListValue"
                [inputFormatter]="inputFormatAgencyListValue"
                [editable]="false"
                [showHint]="true"
                #instance="ngbTypeahead"
                (selectItem)="onSelectItem($event, agencyInput)"
                placeholder="{{
                  '::Contract:AgencyPlaceHolder' | abpLocalization
                }}"
                #agencyInput />
```

Everything is working as expected, except when the user writes something and does not complete or select an option and clicks outside the input, it leaves the input incomplete.

Example:

[image]

As you can see, it has the option because I write "tes", but if I click outside the dropdown:

[image]

I want to clean the dropdown if the user clicks outside the input. How can I do that?